# How to submit a Oracle Java Change Request?

Tags: java, oracle, java-8, rfe

I'd like to submit a Java8 LocalDate API change request (RFE) to Oracle. Unfortunately, the one and only form I could find (http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/) does not provide the fields (Category, Sub-Category, ) I would need to specify me request correctly.

Is there any other way of filing correct and thorough Java change request to Oracle?

Comment: Instead of petitioning Oracle, you'd probably need to contact the specification lead of the relevant JSR (JSR-310).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about raising a change request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this [link](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/issues/#?jql=project%20=%20JDK%20AND%20component%20=%20core-libs%20AND%20status%20in%20%28Open,%20%22In%20Progress%22,%20New%29%20AND%20Subcomponent%20in%20%28%22java.time%22,%20%22java.time%22,%20%22java.time%22%29%20ORDER%20BY%20updated%20DESC) help you? Anyway, you will need an account at Oracle.

The categories are "core-libs" (components) and "java.time" (subcomponent). Am just curious, what would you like to change?

**UPDATE:** I have now got a closer look. It seems the bug report website is not quite uptodate with Java 8, missing the possibility to specify the `java.time`-package. So I would instead try to choose the subcategory "java.util.*" or "JDK/JRE documentation, API, tutorials (doc)" dependent on the kind of your RFE. The categoriy should probably be "Java Platform Standard Edition (JDK/JRE)".

And notice that you can only file bug reports or RFEs, but not request for changing the API in a backwards incompatible manner.

```
Bug: A behavior that violates the specification. 
RFE: A feature that should be added to the product.
```

**Another idea:**

You can try to send an issue on [Threeten/Github](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten/issues).

Comment: How do you register an account there?

Comment: @AaronFranke I have never done it myself, but maybe this [website](https://openjdk.java.net/contribute/) helps. What would you submit? (just for curiosity)

Comment: I'd like to suggest improvements to the javax Color classes, such as changing the arguments `xyzw` to `rgba`, and possibly adding a floating-point color class to `java.awt` as well.